# bind or column index out of range

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I want to delete all data in  an existing sqlite DB, this is the code i am using:

```
sqlite3* database;
databaseName = @"AppDB";
NSString *pathToDatabase;
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
pathToDatabase = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

int databaseReturnCode = sqlite3_open([pathToDatabase UTF8String], &database);
NSLog(@"databaseReturnCode %d",databaseReturnCode);
if(databaseReturnCode == SQLITE_OK) {


    const char *sql = "delete from AppDB";
    sqlite3_stmt *delete_statement;

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &delete_statement, NULL);

    sqlite3_bind_int(delete_statement, 1, 1);

    printf( "error or not an error? :  %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(database) ); 

    sqlite3_reset(delete_statement);

    sqlite3_finalize(delete_statement);

}
sqlite3_close(database);
```

there are more than one field and more than one table in this DB. Please let me know what the error is. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please comment this `sqlite3_bind_int(delete_statement, 1, 1);` line and run the code, Because in query you do not have any parameter which will need binding. Also I wander does this query exists? can you do like this **delete from someDatabase** directly? I don't think there is any query which takes database name! (I hope `AppDB` is table name).

[We should follow standard naming conventions for easy understanding.]

Thanks

Comment: Thanks! it works!! The DB name and the first table are the same, so all the records of the first table are getting deleted . This direct query is happening